# schedule report -ibm cognos

Tags: sql, db2, cognos

I have to schedule a MTD and YTD report out of scheduler in ibm cognos the problem is i have used a store procedure in the frame work manager and  to build the report in the report studio i am  passing start date and end date by using the date prompts  to generate the report . the report is running fine but i want to  schedule the report to run standalone as MTD and YTD .please guide me how to set the dates to default dates in the report studio and  schedule the report to get MTD and YTD data.

Comment: You could alter the stored procedure to conditionally generate the month / year/ date/ if the input parameters are null - that lets you omit any parameters in cognos caller.

Comment: Thank you for the advice ,a little more information on how to make that work in cognos will be appreciated